# Eigenspace and $\ker(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra

It seems like eigenspace and $\ker(T)$ are strongly connected, I have thought about some properties and I would like to make sure I got it right.

1. for all matrix/transformation there is an Eigenspace $\iff 0\in \ker(T) \iff$ a homogeneous system of linear equations has always a trivial solution.
2. there are eigenvectors $\iff$ for some $x$, $x I-A$ is not invertible/full rank/etc.
3. There are eigenvalues $\iff$ there are eigenvectors

Am I right? Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer; please tell me if something is not clear.

0) You're right; the eigenspace and the kernel are related: the eigenspace is the solution to $Ax=\lambda x= x:(A-\lambda I)x =0 $, for $\lambda$ an eigenvalue  of $A$ , so the eigenspace is the kernel of the map $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

1) $0$ ( the zero vector) is *always* in the kernel of any linear map, since $T(0)=T(c.0)=0T(c)=0$. And a matrix does not always have an eigenspace , even if $0$ is in Ker(T). Take, e.g., a matrix with Real entries with characteristic polynomial, e.g., $ \lambda^2 +1$, e.g., the antidiagonal $2\times 2$ matrix with entries $-1,1$ . This matrix will contain no (Real ) eigenvalues.

2) This is false: consider the identity matrix; it is invertible. The whole space is the eigenspace and it has the non-zero eigenvalue $1$. Notice that there is an equivalence between having non-zero determinant and being invertible. An interesting consequence of this is that matrices $M$ with entries over the integers are invertible iff  $Det(M)=1$ or $DetM = -1$.

3)If there I an eigenvalue $\lambda$, then the vector $v$ satisfying $(A -\lambda I)v =0$ is an eigenvector. By construction, $(A- \lambda I)v$ is not invertible, so there are non-trivial solutions , i.e., there are solutions to $(A- \lambda I)v=0$ other than $v=0$.

Comment: Does 1 hold true just for the real numbers?

Comment: @gbox: Sorry, do you mean that $0$ is in the kernel?

Comment: Maybe you mean for algebraically complete fields, every equation splits completely, i.e., has zeros, so that it has eigenvalues.

Comment: I meant that just 0 is in the Kernel

Comment: No, it is true for all linear maps, since $T(0)=T(c.0)= 0.T(c) $ does not depend on the choice of entries.

Comment: Doesn't $M$ invertible $\iff$ $Det(M)\neq 0$ and not just $1$ and $-1$?

Comment: This is true over the Reals, but for integers, we must have $DetM=1$ or $DetM =-1$: assume $M$  has integer entries and it is invertible. Then we must have a matrix $M^{-1}: MM^{-1}=1$. Then $Det(MM^{-1})= DetMDetM^{-1}=DetId =1$. Since both $DetM, DetM^{-1}$ are integers, we must have an integer solution to $ab=1$. Then $a,b$ can only be either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: Missed the integers part

Comment: I mean, we have $Det (AB) =DetA DetB $. Then, if $A$ is invertible, with inverse $B$, we have $AB =I$ , so, since $Det (AB)=Id =DetA Det B$, we have that $Det (AB)=1$ . Now, using $Det (AB)= Det A Det B $ , we get $DetA DetB =1$. Now, both $Det A, DetB$ are integers. So we must have two integers whose product is 1. This only happens if both integes are $1$, or both are $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1, the first statement is not related to the second and third. However, the last two statements are indeed equivalent.

The newly edited 2 is true.

3 is true.

An important thing you're missing is that $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ associated with $\lambda$ if and only if $v$ is non-zero and $v \in \ker(T - \lambda I)$.  By 3, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $T$ has an associated eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 are false, 3 is true. It is always true that $0\in \ker T$.

2 is false since for the identity matrix, all vectors are eigenvectors, for the eigenvalue $1$.

There is an eigenspace if and only if there is an eigenvalue. Furthermore, the number $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if there exists a vector $v\neq 0$ such that $Tv=\lambda v$, which amounts to $(T-\lambda I) v=0,\enspace v\neq 0$. So this means $\ker(T-\lambda I)\neq 0$ or $\det(T-\lambda I)=0$.

Comment: As for 2 I have fixed it to $x*I-A$ is not invertible/full rank/etc.
Is it true now?

Comment: Yes, if you add `for some x` (otherwise it's meaningless).